# Integrating command button events with recordset in access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I am using an unbound form so that I can enter/edit data in a couple of fields (Had to move over from a bound form to handle this). I am adding the prev, next, first and last buttons on my form. How do I integrate this with the FORM_OPEN event where I display my first record. I don't know how to go about to add the cmdLast_Click, cmdNext_Click, cmdFirst_Click, cmdBack_Click events to this. Any help will be much appreciated.

My current FORM_OPEN event is listed below and just displays the first record.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

  sSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 Proc.ProcedureName, Proc.Manager,   Proc.AnnualApprovalDueDate, AprList.ApprovalDate " & _
"FROM Proc INNER JOIN (SELECT AprTrac.ProcedureId, AprTrac.ApprovalDate FROM AprTrac) " & _
"AS AprList ON Proc.ProcedureId=AprList.ProcedureId WHERE MONTH(Proc.AnnualApprovalDueDate)=MONTH(DATE())"

 Set db = CurrentDb
 Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

 Me.txtProcedureName = rs!ProcedureName
 Me.txtManagerName = rs!Manager
 Me.txtAppDueDate = rs!AnnualApprovalDueDate
 Me.txtAppDate = rs!ApprovalDate

rs.Close

' clear main variable values
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
sSQL = ""

End Sub
```

Here is the cmdNext_Click button event that I added but doesn't seem to work, specifically the rs.movenext

```
Private Sub cmdNext_Click()

On Error Resume Next
rs.MoveNext

Debug.Print rs!ProcedureName
Me.txtProcedureName = rs!ProcedureName
Forms!frmProcedures!txtProcedureName = rs!ProcedureName
Debug.Print Forms!frmProcedures!txtProcedureName.Value
Me.txtManagerName = rs!Manager
Me.txtAppDueDate = rs!AnnualApprovalDueDate
Me.txtAppDate = rs!ApprovalDate

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the `rs` in `cmdNext_Click()` a public/global variable? When you click the command button do any errors occur?

Comment: It is a global variable. I removed the on error and that is when I noticed that the rs is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

If the rs is global as you mentioned, then you want to keep it open at the end of the Form_Open event.  When you close the recordset and then set it to nothing and then try to access it later in your button events, you are accessing rs which is set to nothing.  Remove the rs.close and set rs = nothing lines.

Once you do this, the cmdNext_Click event should work.  As a caution, instead of "rs.MoveNext" you should check the recordset:

```
If rs.EOF Then
    MsgBox("You are already at the end of the recordset!")
Else
    rs.MoveNext
    'rest of code

End If
```

You should similarly do checks for the cmdPrev_Click and other events.

Additionally, in your form_open event, you should choose the record that you want to start with by setting it to either rs.MoveFirst or rs.MoveLast depending on which value you want to default to.  You should also put in some checks to make sure that the recordset is not empty:

```
If rs.EOF and rs.BOF Then
    'Do not initialize fields
Else
    rs.MoveFirst 'or rs.MoveLast....
    'initialize textboxes 
End If
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did comment them out and still they did not work. I had to move away from this approach and incorporated a different approach using the ADO. I will add the solution below

Comment: Is it the same error where the recordset is not recognized?  Was it on the "rs.MoveNext" line?  Had you put in the "rs.MoveFirst" line?  How is the recordset declared?

Comment: no.. the rs.movenext didn't cause an error. it was when I tried to print it Debug.Print rs!ProcedureName

Comment: Is the error "No Current Record"? If so, this is because your original code is only getting the "TOP 1" record, so the recordset only has one value in it. When you move next, the cursor is on RS.EOF, and so when you try to view the "ProcedureName" field, it causes an error. You should be able remove the Connection and use the original code to open the recordset.

Comment: However, what you've done in your answer has added a bunch of checks that will prevent errors from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to get this to work. Maybe I was doing something else wrong while I was at it. If there are any suggestions to make this code more efficient, the suggestions are more than welcome

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)


Dim sSQL As String

sSQL = "SELECT Proc.ProcedureName, Proc.Manager, Proc.AnnualApprovalDueDate, AprList.ApprovalDate " & _
"FROM Proc INNER JOIN (SELECT AprTrac.ProcedureId, AprTrac.ApprovalDate FROM AprTrac) " & _
"AS AprList ON Proc.ProcedureId=AprList.ProcedureId WHERE MONTH(Proc.AnnualApprovalDueDate)=MONTH(DATE())"

Set cnn1 = New ADODB.Connection
mydb = "C:\Users\temp\Documents\Tasks.accdb"
strCnn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & mydb
cnn1.Open strCnn

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sSQL, cnn1, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

rs.MoveLast    
rs.MoveFirst

MoveValues 'Just to pick up the values in the recordset and transfer them to the form

End Sub

Private Sub MoveValues()
With Me
    .txtProcedureName = rs("ProcedureName")
    .txtManagerName = rs("Manager")
    .txtAppDueDate = rs("AnnualApprovalDueDate")
    .txtAppDate = rs("ApprovalDate")
End With
End Sub

Private Sub cmdNext_Click()

On Error Resume Next
rs.MoveNext

cmdDummy.SetFocus

If rs.AbsolutePosition = rs.RecordCount Then
    Me.cmdNext.Enabled = False
    Me.cmdLast.Enabled = False
End If

Me.cmdFirst.Enabled = True
Me.cmdBack.Enabled = True

MoveValues
End Sub

Private Sub cmdBack_Click()

On Error Resume Next
rs.MovePrevious
cmdDummy.SetFocus

If rs.AbsolutePosition = 1 Then
    Me.cmdBack.Enabled = False
    Me.cmdFirst.Enabled = False
End If

Me.cmdNext.Enabled = True
Me.cmdLast.Enabled = True

MoveValues
End Sub

Private Sub cmdFirst_Click()

On Error Resume Next
rs.MoveFirst

cmdDummy.SetFocus

Me.cmdBack.Enabled = False
Me.cmdFirst.Enabled = False

Me.cmdNext.Enabled = True
Me.cmdLast.Enabled = True

MoveValues
End Sub

Private Sub cmdLast_Click()

On Error Resume Next
rs.MoveLast
cmdDummy.SetFocus

Me.cmdBack.Enabled = True
Me.cmdFirst.Enabled = True

Me.cmdNext.Enabled = False
Me.cmdLast.Enabled = False

MoveValues
End Sub
```